# Array not passing from Python Eel to Javascript

Tags: javascript, callback, null, eel

Hi I'm currently working on a desktop app using Python Eel, JS and HTML, but cannot seem to get a Python List to pass into JS for a new function. The Python side is working fine as it prints out the list of expected file names for me. If I insert an let array = ['a','b','c'] into the JS script then I get 3 buttons labelled as so, however when trying to pass the list from Python to JS it doesn't work and I am getting a callback=null error. I've tried multiple ways of fixing this but can't seem to find the answer! (PS: I have tried with the json lines both commented and uncommented and neither of these worked).

Python Script:

```
@eel.expose
def OverView_Data():
    Acc_Files = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Bex\\Records\\Accessioning")
    Acc_Files = [x[:-4] for x in Acc_Files]
    #Acc_Files = json.dumps(Acc_Files)
    #Acc_Files = json.loads(Acc_Files)
    print(Acc_Files)
    return (Acc_Files)
```

JS Script:

```
eel.expose(OverView);
async function OverView(){
    let Array = await eel.OverView_Data()
    console.log(Array)
    for (var i=0; i<Array.length; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode(Array[i]);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line instead:

```py
let Array = await eel.OverView_Data()();
```

The difference is that `()` on the end of your existing line. You can read more about why this approach is needed on the [Eel documentation](https://github.com/ChrisKnott/Eel) page (just search page for `await` for the relevant section).

Lastly, an unrelated suggestion... you should consider avoiding the use of a JavaScript variable named `Array` since [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is a Global object in JavaScript and it could cause some problems.